# Displaying different data even if the ID and Type is right

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I have a code that will display the data in the table from database which has an ID and Type, when the ID = 1 and Type = 1, it will get the data of the Type 1 with the ID 1, but instead it displays the ID 1 of the Type 2 rather than Type 1.

Here's the code for getting all the data in the two tables.

```
public List<DeviceViewModel> DeviceGetAll()
    {
        OfficeManager officeManager = new OfficeManager();
        List<DeviceViewModel> deviceViewModels = new List<DeviceViewModel>();
        List<Workpoint> workpointGetAll = WorkpointGetAll();
        List<Office> offices = officeManager.OfficeGetAll();
        List<Hub> hubs = HubGetAll();
        List<Floor> floors = officeManager.FloorGetAll();
        foreach (Hub hub in hubs)
        {
            DeviceViewModel deviceItems = new DeviceViewModel();
            deviceItems.ID = hub.ID;
            deviceItems.Name = hub.Name;
            deviceItems.Type = 2;
            deviceItems.MAC = hub.MAC;
            deviceItems.IPaddress = hub.IPaddress;
            deviceItems.OfficeID = hub.OfficeID;
            deviceItems.IsActive = hub.IsActive;
            deviceItems.IsDeleted = hub.IsDeleted;
            try
            {
                deviceItems.FloorID = hub.FloorID;
                deviceItems.RoomID = hub.RoomID;
                deviceItems.OfficeName = offices.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ID.Equals(hub.OfficeID)).Name;
                deviceItems.Floor = floors.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ID.Equals(hub.FloorID)).Name;
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            deviceViewModels.Add(deviceItems);
        }
        foreach (Workpoint workpoint in workpointGetAll)
        {
            DeviceViewModel deviceItems = new DeviceViewModel();
            deviceItems.ID = workpoint.ID;
            deviceItems.Name = workpoint.Name;
            deviceItems.Type = 1;
            deviceItems.MAC = workpoint.MAC;
            deviceItems.IPaddress = workpoint.IPaddress;
            try
            {
                deviceItems.OfficeID = workpoint.OfficeID;
                deviceItems.FloorID = workpoint.FloorID;
                deviceItems.RoomID = workpoint.RoomID;
                deviceItems.OfficeName = offices.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ID.Equals(workpoint.OfficeID)).Name;
                deviceItems.Floor = floors.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ID.Equals(workpoint.FloorID)).Name;
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            deviceViewModels.Add(deviceItems);
        }
        return deviceViewModels;
    }
```

Here's my controller.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Details(int id, int type)
    {
        return View(deviceManager.DeviceGetAll(id, type));
    }
```

Comment: Add code please...

Comment: And not clear to me - *when the ID = 1 and Type = 1, it will get the data of the Type 1 with the ID 1, but instead it displays the ID 1 of the Type 2 rather than Type 1.*

Comment: I added the code for getting all the datas.

Comment: Ahh ok, i see your new at this, please don't paste images of code, we cant copy and paste code in images, its also hard to read. Just add the real code thanks

Comment: I changed it already.

Comment: What do you expect from the above code. I find it difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve from the above code snippet. Please be more clear in your question.

Comment: So, I have two tables in database, the Workpoint (Type 1) and Hub (Type 2) and I have a view that will display the data in Workpoint(Type 1) which is the ID = 1, but instead it display the Hub(Type 2) with the ID = 1.

Comment: Did you paste the correct code? The two `DeviceGetAll` methods don't have the same signatures.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed the error, it's in the manager, I forgot to put the type in query params. Thanks guys.